# Why are 2 extra reputation points shown?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, reputation

The dropdown under my name on SO shows

```
           today week month
reputation  21  41  1063
votes cast  2   2   21
revisions   0   0   2
favorites   0   0   2
+2  sears credit card starts with 50 — fails regex
-1  Implement IEquatable for POCO
+10 Configure WCF for WS-Security with Username ove…
+10 How can I generate random 8 character, alphanum…
```

However, /reputation for the last several days shows

```
-- 2012-11-16 rep +32   = 47149     
 2   3630707 (10)
-- 2012-11-17 rep +10   = 47159     
 2  13354955 (10)
 2  12784567 (10)
-- 2012-11-18 rep +20   = 47179     
 2   1344255 (10)
 2   4551681 (10)
 3   9782522 (-1)
-- 2012-11-19 rep +19   = 47198
```

Where is that extra +2 (in the display for today's reputation) for ["sears credit card starts with 50 — fails regex"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350745/sears-credit-card-starts-with-50-fails-regex/13350802#13350802) coming from?

Is it a bug?

Comment: I don't agree that this should be closed for being "too localized".  The issue is about a disconnect between information shown on the dropdown and the reputation tab of the profile for "today" and information shown on /reputation for "today" (the definitions of "today" seem to be different).  That user experience issue would affect any user.  Perhaps there is a duplicate out there that would justify closing.

Comment: Why are you checking /reputation instead of your actual reputation history in the first place? Did you not check your reputation history first before going there? As far as I'm aware, the /reputation page isn't even maintained anymore (officially their stance is still "it's going to be removed" from back when they did the reputation history overhaul).

Comment: @EricJ. Don't get too hung up on this particular closure. It's seemingly common practice here on Meta for questions like these where a perceived bug/issue isn't really one. If you feel something particularly problematic has been left unaddressed, please do say so. If you fear this might be deleted at some point, I don't see that as likely to happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's caused by an undownvote, as stated with the [reputation tab of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141172/eric-j?tab=reputation).

[image]

Comment: Ah... so I did not find it in the /reputation URL because it applied on the day of the original downvote?

Comment: @EricJ. I am not entirely sure how the /reputation page is formed, but I would assume it's either listed for that day, or removed from there altogether.